# Joining tables with one key and multiple repeating values of the key on the other

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, join

I'm struggling to combine two sheets using the column of one as a key, and XLOOKUP is no help since the second sheet has multiple rows that match each of the key rows in the first.

Sheet A has 65 unique IDs and no other data. Sheet B has 20,000+ rows which contain 1000s of IDs and the information I'm looking to get for each of my 65 IDs. Each of the 65 IDs in Sheet B has 1+ rows of unique data that I want to keep.

Basically the need to isolate 65 IDs in this 1000+ ID Sheet B to then work with the remaining data and I haven't been able to find a clean way to do this that doesn't force me to do it with one ID at a time.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Sample of sheet A

[image: Sample of sheet A]

Sample of sheet B

[image: Sample of sheet B]

What ideal combo should look like

[image: What ideal combo should look like]

Comment: can you just applying a filter to your sheet B, or the `filter` formula might be what you want.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach, just edit the range references to suit your actual ranges:  (data is in A11:B27, bare ID's are in A1:A5)

```
=SORT(  FILTER(  A11:B27,  MATCH(A11:A27, A1:A5, 0) >= 1  )  )
```

or using descriptors instead:

```
=SORT(  FILTER(  Data,  MATCH(DataIDs, BareIDList, 0) >= 1  )  )
```

If your desired return of columns from those available in the data range is not "all of them", you can wrap the above with an `INDEX` function, specifying the column numbers you wish in an "array constant" in the column parameter. So if you want columns 1, 2, 3, 6, 10, and 43, you'd use `{1,2,3,6,10,43}`. You can do this also if you wish to rearrange them in the output or to use one more than once. So if wanting the shown set, but you want column 43 in the third place in the result and you want column 2 in three places, it might look like `{1,2,43,6,2,2,10}`.

`MATCH` is used to give a basis for a comparison that ends up true or false, but will check one ID at a time. Just specifying "Data = BareIDList" fails since no ID in the Data range matches ALL the desired ID's. `MATCH` is able to do them one at a time instead of all at once.